# Difference between "it would later be" and "it was later to be"

Tags: expressions

It feels like "it would later be" is ungrammatical

while "it was later to be" or "it later became" sounds fine.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide some examples in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It would later be..." could be used when writing about the *past* to inject a statement about something that has already happened but is later than the narrative, for example:

> John wrote the novel which would later be adapted into a movie.

This is talking about the *past*, when John wrote a book, but it notes that it was later made into a movie.

"It would later *to* be" does not sound correct at all. The tense of the unconjugated verb does not work with "would". You could instead say:

> The novel *was* later *to be* adapted into a movie.